# Why does the client fetched data appear in view source for Angular SSR/universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Can somebody explain to me why the fetched data appears in the view source when you do client side navigation?

I have this code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.users$ = this.http.get('api/users');
  }
```

I'm doing the navigation on the client, to that component with `routerLink="my-component"`.

Running the project with `npm run dev:ssr`

The call is made on the client, not the server, but somehow, the data is in the page source.

I've worked on VUE SSR projects and when the client navigation starts, if you inspect the page source, you don't find the data there, but I see that in angular, it appears. What is the cause for this?

Thanks

Comment: Hm... Mayer it's because I'm using ngIf={users$ | async as users} ? In the view source it's the data that is fetched.  I'm using a ngFor that goes through the fetched users and {{user.name}}, just for demo purposes.

Comment: That is the entire goal of SSR.. right..?

Comment: Well, if it's client side and not being rendered from the server, it's not SSR anymore. The res.render() on the server is not called and the http call is in the browser's network. That's why I need to understand how the view source is updated. I have another button that makes a http call that updates the view when you click it, and this doesn't appear in the view source.

Comment: Using resolver and session storage we can achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76406951/714707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation in Angular, with console logs in platform-browser, platform-server, core, transfer state, breakpoints in dev tools, I realized that the browser was the "issue". Something I didn't know happened by default.

What was happening was that when hitting view source like `view-source:http://localhost:4200/my-component`, if that page was never loaded from the server, the browser makes an http call to the server and loads the data in the view source. Then it caches that view source.

If you go again on the client side to that route, and call view source again, the browser serves you the cached version and that's why you don't see anything in the server console.

When I was playing with the app I must have loaded all of the pages from the server and then when navigating on the client side I was getting the cached version of the view source without seeing any server calls.